# Applying CLT and Law of Large Numbers to a non-standard sequence involving normal distribution

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

Suppose that $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{+\infty}$ is an i.i.d sequence distributed as $N(0, \sigma^2)$.

Let
$$U_n := \dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} |X_j|$$
$$V_n := \dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} X_j^2$$

The question is where does $P_n := \sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{V_n}{U_n} - \sigma\right)$ converge by distribution?

What I did:

1. By the law of large numbers, $U_n \to E|X_1| = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sigma$ and $V_n \to EX_1^2 = \sigma^2$ (convergence in probability and, hence, weak convergence as well).
2. I managed to represent $P_n$ as $\alpha A_n + \beta B_n$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants, and $A_n$, $B_n$ both converge to $A, B \sim N(0, 1)$ by CLT. However, that doesn't mean that the sequence converges to $\alpha A + \beta B$, as far as I understand (in general, we can't add it like that).
3. Maybe the [delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method#Univariate_delta_method) could help? But not sure, how to apply it here.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity's sake, let's denote the symbol $\sim$ as "be asymptotically equal to ... in distribution" for $n \to +\infty$. Example: $X_n \sim Y_n$ means $X_n$ follows asymptotically the distribution of $Y_n$ when $n \to +\infty$.

Let's recall the distribution of $U_n$ and $V_n$ (by using the CLT):

$$U_n \sim E(|X|)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \mathcal{N}(0,V(|X|))$$
$$V_n \sim E(X^2)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \mathcal{N}(0,V(X^2))$$

Applying the Taylor developpement on $\frac{V_n}{U_n}$
\begin{align}
\frac{V_n}{U_n} &\sim \left(E(|X|)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \mathcal{N}(0,V(|X|))\right) \left(E(X^2)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \mathcal{N}(0,V(X^2))\right)^{-1} \\
&\sim \frac{1}{E(X^2)}\left(E(|X|)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \mathcal{N}(0,V(|X|))\right) \left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \frac{\mathcal{N}(0,V(X^2))}{E(X^2)}\right)^{-1} \\
&\sim \frac{1}{E(X^2)}\left(E(|X|)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \mathcal{N}(0,V(|X|))\right) \left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \frac{\mathcal{N}(0,V(X^2))}{E(X^2)}\right) \\
&\sim \frac{1}{E(X^2)}\left(E(|X|)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \left( \mathcal{N}(0,V(|X|)) +\frac{\mathcal{N}(0,V(X^2))}{E(X^2)}\right) +\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n})
 \right)  \\
&\sim \frac{E(|X|)}{E(X^2)}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \left(\frac{ \mathcal{N}(0,V(|X|)) }{E(X^2)}+\frac{\mathcal{N}(0,V(X^2))}{E^2(X^2)}\right) +\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n})
 \\
\end{align}

Hence,
$$P_n = \sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{V_n}{U_n}-\sigma \right) \sim \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\mathcal{N}\left(0,\frac{V(|X|)}{E^2(X^2)} +\frac{V(X^2)}{E^4(X^2)} \right) $$
or

$$P_n \xrightarrow{n\to +\infty} \mathcal{N}\left(0,\frac{2}{\pi}\left(\frac{V(|X|)}{E^2(X^2)} +\frac{V(X^2)}{E^4(X^2)} \right)\right) $$

Comment: Are you saying that for any $n$ it's true that $U_n \sim E(|X|)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \mathcal{N}(0,V(|X|))$? But for $n=1$ that would mean $|X_1| \sim N(E|X|, V|X|)$ which is not true, because $|X_i|$ is not normally distributed (and neither is $X_i^2)$.

Comment: @Swistack The symbol ~ means "be asymptotically equal to" for $n \to +\infty$.

Comment: That makes sense now. Thank you for your answer and clarification.